# Powershell doesn't have some builtin help topics

Tags: powershell

I found my powershell doesn't have some help topics like `about_profiles`. I tried `update-help` but it doesn't help. Can anyone help to take a look?

```
PS C:\> systeminfo

Host Name:                 ******************
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
OS Version:                10.0.10586 N/A Build 10586
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          ******
Registered Organization:
Product ID:                *********************
Original Install Date:     7/29/2016, 1:55:43 AM
System Boot Time:          8/2/2016, 1:39:10 AM
System Manufacturer:       LENOVO
System Model:              *********
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3 GenuineIntel ~2494 Mhz
BIOS Version:              LENOVO GNET75WW (2.23 ), 9/1/2015
Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
Time Zone:                 
Total Physical Memory:     16,009 MB
Available Physical Memory: 10,029 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  18,953 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 11,073 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    7,880 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    WORKGROUP
Logon Server:              
Hotfix(s):                 1 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB3116278
Network Card(s):           5 NIC(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM
                                 Connection Name: Ethernet
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 
                                 [02]: 
                           [02]: Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
                                 Connection Name: Wi-Fi
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [03]: TeamViewer VPN Adapter
                                 Connection Name: Ethernet 2
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [04]: VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
                                 Connection Name: VMware Network Adapter VMnet1
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 
                                 [02]: 
                           [05]: VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
                                 Connection Name: VMware Network Adapter VMnet8
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 
                                 [02]: 
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
PS C:\> help profile

Name                              Category  Module                    Synopsis
----                              --------  ------                    --------
Get-NetConnectionProfile          Function  NetConnection             ...
Set-NetConnectionProfile          Function  NetConnection             ...
Get-NetFirewallProfile            Function  NetSecurity               ...
Set-NetFirewallProfile            Function  NetSecurity               ...
Disable-NetIPHttpsProfile         Function  NetworkTransition         ...
Enable-NetIPHttpsProfile          Function  NetworkTransition         ...



PS C:\>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [known bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2028#issuecomment-246152335) with WMF5 (PowerShell 5) where it will not update the help files because Microsoft didn't package them correctly.

If you're on an updated version of PowerShell, you should be able to run `Install-Script -Name Install-AboutHelp` followed by `Install-AboutHelp.ps1`.