# PowerShell: no results returned for `Help about*` and Update-Help crashes

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get familiar with PowerShell by reading *PowerShell 3 in a month of lunches* by D. Jones and J. Hicks.

They mention how to access the *About_* topics early on. So I typed in `Help About*`, which surprisingly, did not return any results.

Then I tried the Update-Help command, thinking maybe those topics weren't pulled in. The following is the error I got:

```
Update-Help : Failed to update Help for the module(s) 'SecureBoot'
with UI culture(s) {en-GB} : Unable to  retrieve the HelpInfo XML file
for UI culture en-GB. Make sure the HelpInfoUri property in the module
manifest  is valid or check your network connection and then try the
command again.

At line:1 char:1

Update-Help

~~~~~~~~~~~

CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Update-Help], Exception

FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToRetrieveHelpInfoXml, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UpdateHelpCommand
```

So I googled a bit and came across the command `Test-ModuleManifest` which supposedly pulls up the module information for the specified module. So I ran:

```
Test-ModuleManifest SecureBoot
```

After which I got the error:

```
Test-ModuleManifest : The specified module 'SecureBoot' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

At line:1 char:1

Test-ModuleManifest SecureBoot

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (SecureBoot:String) [Test-ModuleManifest], FileNotFoundException

FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestModuleManifestCommand
```

So at this point I don't know how to proceed.

My main questions are

- Why `Help About*` doesn't return any results?
- How do I run `Update-Help` without having the thing crash?

Edit: Here are my PSVersionTable information:

**PSVersion** = 5.0.10586.494

**PSCompatibleVersions** = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}

**BuildVersion** = 10.0.10586.494

**CLRVersion** = 4.0.30319.42000

**WSManStackVersion** = 3.0

**PSRemotingProtocolVersion** = 2.3

**SerializationVersion** = 1.1.0.1

**Edit**:

The following series of steps installs the `about_*` topics.

```
Install-Script -Name Install-AboutHelp
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Install-AboutHelp.ps1
Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted
```

As far as updating the documentation for the `SecureBoot` module goes, I tried JosefZ's suggestion:

```
Test-ModuleManifest (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name SecureBoot).Path
```

This gave me the following warning:

```
WARNING: The module manifest member 'ModuleToProcess' has been deprecated. Use the 'RootModule' member instead.

ModuleType Version    Name           ExportedCommands
-----------------------------------------------------
Binary     2.0.0.0    SecureBoot     {Confirm-SecureBootUEFI, Set-SecureBootUEFI, Get-S...
```

I tried finding the Location of SecureBoot:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name SecureBoot
Directory: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
```

HelpInfoURI property in SecureBoot.psd1 points to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=390823

This resolves to http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/A/9/CA9A7C18-3808-4984-A92F-1EF9398F36F9/

Which when opened by the browser gives me a *File not found* error.

Also, I have now tried running `Update-Help` with `UICulture` parameter set to en-US, and unfortunately I've got the same error.

Comment: `Test-ModuleManifest (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name SecureBoot).Path`

Comment: Part of your issue is localization, see this [post for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003380/get-help-about-doesnt-work-on-non-english-system)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell doesn't have some builtin help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39553437/powershell-doesnt-have-some-builtin-help-topics)